# How to select all the tags "a" in the current child node?

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

In HtmlAgilityPach, when I'm selecting one node like this:

```
  var node1 = htmlDoc.GetElementbyId("some_id");
```

I want to get all child "a" tags in its children. However, this doesn't work because it returns null:

```
foreach (var childItem in node1.ChildNodes) {
  var a = childItem.SelectNodes("a") // null
  var a = childItem.SelectNodes("/a") // null
  var a = childItem.SelectNodes("//a") // not null but select all the "a" tags on the whole(!) page, not only the ones within current childItem
}
```

As you can see, the last methods selects all the "a" tags on the whole(!) page, not only the ones within current childItem. I wonder why and how to make it select the ones only in "childNode"?

Comment: Try childItem.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add a dot (`.`) at the beginning of the XPath to make it relative to current `childItem` :

```
var a = childItem.SelectNodes(".//a");
```

Comment: but doesn't "childItem" make it relative? Why not?

Comment: Not necessarily. When the XPath begins with `/` the context will be the root element, ignoring whatever element you're executing the XPath on